# Why if I change background of my RelativeLayout the positions of the items of the Layout change?

Tags: android

I do not understand, why If a put a background image to my RelativeLayout the views in the Layout (Buttons, Edittext, TextViews) get all misplaced.

This is how it looks before I put the background image:

[image]

This is the XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@android:color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bikenumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/getbikebutton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Get Bikes"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/getbikebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:text="FindBikes" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonGoToMyLoc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:text="NearMe" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonGoToThisLoc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonGoToMyLoc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Near Address" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/locAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Addresss"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/locAddressCity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/locAddress"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Address City"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Now if I put this image as a background:

[image]

So if I put `android:background="@drawable/bgland"`, this is how my layout looks like:

[image]

As you can see the Layout misplaces the Buttons.

Comment: yeah you are right, I have imported your code in my eclipse and its really making it very weird when you set background.

Comment: @Lisa try to give background to LinearLayout, I think it will work.

Comment: @pratik Hi pratik, thanks you :-) unfortunately I have tried to set the image as background of the LinearLayout, but no success :-(( nothing changes :-((

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
Put the Background in the ScrollView.